# Customized attribute for each collection checkbox in symfony2 form

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I have a class with title and description attributes and a have created a collection form with multiple checkboxes.

Can i set as title attribute for each checkbox the description of entity?

The class:

```
class Carpeta {   
    private $id;
    private $titulo;
    private $descripcion;
[...]
}
```

The Form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
[...]
$builder->add(
            'carpetas',
            'entity',
            array(
                'label' => 'str_documentacion_necesaria_general',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'class' => 'Itbid\DirectorioBundle\Entity\Carpeta',
                'attr'=> array('class'=>'span12'),
                'choices' => $this->em->getRepository('DirectorioBundle:Carpeta')->findAll()
            )
        );
[...]
}
```

The View:

```
[...]
{{ form_widget(form.carpetas) }}
[...]
```

Comment: Can you show us a short example of your form in twig? And can you explain what is your flow?

Comment: Each "carpeta" needs a title attribute with the description value.

Comment: to modify form_widget rendering you must make a custom form theme  [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) you can look at form_div_layout.html.twig

Comment: I know http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#twig-reference-form-variables

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in twig while rendering the widget.

Iterate the children of the form element and render each option indiviually.

```
{% for key, item in form.property.children %}
    {%  if item.vars.value == 'one' %}
        {%  set title = "Title for choice one" %}
    {%  elseif item.vars.value == 'two' %}
        {%  set title = "Title for choice two" %}
    {% else %}
        {%  set title = "" %}
    {% endif %}

    {{ form_widget(item, {attr: {title: title}}) }}
    {{ form_label(item, null, {
        'label_attr': {'title': title}
    }) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand but if you want to set the title attribute of your HTML tag you can do something like this

```
{{ form_widget(form.property, {attr: {title: form.property.description}}) }}
```

The second argument of form_widget lets you set your HTML attributes